# how to trigger the second button only after triggering the first button

Tags: jquery, html

I want to make the second button click event to work only after the first button click event works . Second button's click event must not work before clicking the first button.

```
 <div class = "panel1">
 <button>button1</button>
 <p>Button 1 triggered</p>
</div>
<div class = "panel2">
<button>button1</button>
<p>Button 2 triggered</p>
</div>

 p{
 display:none;
} 


  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings("p").toggle();
      });
     })
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/Gautham007/q8cyd2mr/4/)

Comment: could you trigger true / false on completion of button 1 that button 2 checks before activating ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the solution below:

https://jsfiddle.net/q8cyd2mr/6/

HTML part:

```
<div class = "panel1">
      <button>button1</button>
      <p>Button 1 triggered</p>
    </div>
    <div class = "panel2">
      <button>button2</button>
      <p>Button 2 triggered</p>
</div>
```

JS part:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".panel2 button").prop('disabled', true);
    $("button").click(function(){
        $(this).siblings("p").toggle();
        if($(this).parent().prop("class")=='panel1'){
          $(".panel2 button").prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would start of by making the second button disabled by default. Then enable it after the user has clicked on the first button. I provided you with some code of how that would look, I hope this helps.

HTML:

```
<div class = "panel1">
    <button>button1</button>
    <p>Button 1 triggered</p>
</div>
<div class = "panel2">
    <button disabled>button1</button>
    <p>Button 2 triggered</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
p{
    display: none;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".panel1 button").click(function(){
      $(this).siblings("p").toggle();
      $(".panel2 button").prop("disabled", false);
  });
  $(".panel2 button").click(function(){
      $(this).siblings("p").toggle();
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could solve your problem with the disabled-property.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(button2).prop('disabled', true);
    $(button1).click(function() {
        $(button2).prop('disabled', false);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".firstbutton").on("click", function(evt){
// custon script 
   $("#secondbutton").trigger("click");
 });
```

Comment: code-only answers aren't useful to the community. Please look at [answer]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can make the second button click event to work only after the first button click event like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".panel1 button").click(function(){
        $(this).siblings("p").toggle();
        $(".panel2 button").click(function(){
          $(this).siblings("p").toggle();
        });
    });
})
```

Answer (score -1):

additional to two of those methods you can keep a Boolean variable and check whether its true before performing the second method.after performing make it false again.and enable it in first buttons click event method
Better practice is disabling though

Comment: the method of adding the second event inside the first event function wont help because when u do the action for the second time event listener is already added